# Tapestry5 - Show Tree component in the DOM

Tags: javascript, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 5 and this component to show a list of folders :

http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Tree.html

The problem is that there is only the root element that is shown in the DOM so I can't apply javascript listeners to the rest of the element. And I need to.

Do you have an idea of what to do ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, share your code. You must be adding these listeners for a reason, what your final goal?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the coffee script [here](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/93168cd8d836fbfeadf52ed27b7e9fb28832c4ce/tapestry-core/src/main/coffeescript/META-INF/modules/t5/core/tree.coffee) I can't see any clientside events being fired.

You might have to use the `nodeSelected` and `nodeUnselected` events serverside to send scripts to be executed on the client via [JavascriptSupport.addScript(...)](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/javascript/JavaScriptSupport.html)

eg:

```
public class MyPage {
   @Inject JavaScriptSupport jss;
   @InjectComponent Tree tree;

   void onNodeSelected(String nodeId) {
      jss.addScript(InitializationPriority.LATE, "alert('%s.%s selected');", tree.getClientId(), nodeId);
   }
   void onNodeUnselected(String nodeId) {
      jss.addScript(InitializationPriority.LATE, "alert('%s.%s un-selected');", tree.getClientId(), nodeId);
   }
}
```